# Jenkins Jira Plugin SSL Authentication issue

Tags: authentication, jenkins, https, jira, keystore

Good day.

I'm trying to realize integration Jenkis/Bitbucket Server/Jira Server.
All servers are working under SSL (Private PKI) with Peer authentication enabled.

So first step is to connect to BitBucket and it was successfull.
Everything i've done is added JVM_ARGS to jenkins

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/ssl/jenkins.p12 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/ssl/cacerts 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=JenkinsPassword1 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

So Jenkins authenticated on BitBucket.

After that i tried to connect Jenkins to JIRA. And without a success.

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
```

All servers have certificates deployed under same CA chain.
All servers have that chain in trust store.

So i wonder what i'm doing wrong?
I've enbled SSL debug (javax.net.debug=ssl).

And saw follwing strings during jira site configuration validation:

```
Found trusted certificate: //So there is no problem with truststore.
....
....
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication // WHY?? 
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
```

But with bitbucket server it picks right certificate.
Double cheked everything, moreover, bitbucket server is working good.

Some dig in code i found that JIRA Plugins uses Attlasians Library, which is uses Apache HTTP Client. And i could not understand why HTTP Client not initializing keystore for JIRA Connection.

May be someone faced same problem? Any solution without rfactoring Plugin or libraries?

Any suggestions are welcome.

I'm using Jenkins 2.89.2 with Jira Plugin 2.5 /Bitbucket Server 5.3/ Jira 7.63
Jenkins running in docker.

PS: Skip Certificate Verification Plugin not an option. Peer authentication is mandatory.

Comment: Hi Dmirty, did you figure out this issue ? Facing similar siutation

Comment: Any news on this? I am really struggling with all sorts of plugins not finding my certificates in keystore

Comment: I gived up.  So I just disabled ssl client auth. Probably I'll need to check with  fresh version. But all I understood - there is some chaos with keystores in Jenkins. Because some times HTTPClient is used, and you not able to configure something through environment or whatever.